# ヒアドキュメントの最後の改行を除去することは不可能？　一般的にputsとは一緒に使わない？

Tags: ruby

### ネットでよく見かけるソース

```
def hoge
  foo = '12345'
  a = <<~EOS
    foo: #{foo}
  EOS
end

print hoge
```

### 結果

```
foo: 12345
#<-改行されている
```

### 下記はエラー

```
def hoge
  foo = '12345'
  a = <<~EOS
    foo: #{foo}\
  EOS
end
```

### エラー内容

`can't find string "EOS" anywhere before EOF`

### 質問

特に問題がないと言えば問題がないですが、ヒアドキュメントによって作られた文字列を含む変数などを`puts`で表示させると`ヒアドキュメントの最後の改行`と`putsの改行`のダブルの改行が出力されるわけです。一般的にヒアドキュメントの場合は`puts`とは一緒に使わないのでしょうか？　最後の改行を除去する方法はありますか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`puts`に末尾が改行で終わっている文字列を渡しても、改行は1つしか出ません。
なのでヒアドキュメントの場合も`puts`と一緒に使うことはよくあります。

> 末尾が改行で終っている引数や配列の要素に対しては puts 自身 は改行を出力しません。 
>   http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.3.0/class/Kernel.html#M_PUTS
>
> Writes a record separator (typically a newline) after any that do not already end with a newline sequence.
>   http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-i-puts

Answer (score 2):

`a.chomp` または `a.chomp!` します。

リファレンス：[chomp](http://ref.xaio.jp/ruby/classes/string/chomp)

ヒアドキュメント自体は行単位の入力なのでヒアドキュメントの入力指定での改行削除はないと思います。

Comment: 同じことではありますけれども、`a = <<~EOS.chomp` とする事もできます。

Comment: これって`-`(ハイフン)じゃないんですかね？（チルダでなくて）、今更ですけど私の使ってるバージョンが古いのかな。

Comment: こちらは ruby 2.3.1 ですが、ハイフンだと行頭のスペースがそのままになります("    foo:12345" と表示されます)。

Comment: なるほど！私が使っているのはruby 1.9.2です。（チルダだとエラーになる） やっぱり（バージョンの違い）でしたか。変に指摘したりしないでよかった。 同じことなら`a = <<~EOS.chomp` の方がいいですね。